# MsBuild error MSB3202: The project file "http://localhost/xxx" was not found

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

We started using InstallShield recently. We have a couple of websites, not web application projects, in our solution, along with a bunch of C# projects. These websites have references to the other C# projects. When building isproj in Visual Studio, everything is fine. But when building the solution in command-line, on the same dev machine, using the stand alone build, isproj would throw the following error on both websites:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2012Spring\InstallShield.targets
(14,3): error MSB3202: The project file "http://localhost/xxx" was not
 found.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: checked this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269998/getting-msbuild-error-msb3202-when-running-a-build-with-teamcity

Answer (score 0):

Actually we contacted InstallShield. The don't support websites. They only support web projects. We had to work around this problem by building our websites separately using other VS commands, and grabbing the files afterwards.